# Struct template and constructor with initializer list

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

I'm trying to better understand templates and for this purpose I made an educational struct:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct SVectorN
{
    SVectorN(const T(&another)[N]);
private:
    T components[N];
};
```

Constructor that I made allows me to make an instance, like this:

```
double input[4] = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 };
SVectorN<double, 4> t(input);
```

But I can't figure out how to support initializating like this:

```
SVectorN<double, 4> c = { 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 };
```

Or even better something like this:

```
SVectorN c(1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 ); // SVectorN<double, 4>
```

Is it possible or am I missing something comepletely?

Thanks

Comment: I think you would need a constructor with a signature that looks like: SVectorN(std::initializer_list<T> list);

Comment: A constructor taking a `std::initializer_list<T>` will work for `SVectorN<double, 4> c = { 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 };` but will not work for `SVectorN c(1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 );` You would need a constructor using a variadic template for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are possible, initialization in C++ is tricky simply because of how many ways there are and their subtle differences.

I would recommend something like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t N> struct SVectorN {
    SVectorN(const T (&another)[N]);

    template <typename First, typename Second, typename... Tail>
    SVectorN(First &&f, Second &&s, Tail &&...t)
        : components{std::forward<First>(f), std::forward<Second>(s),
                     std::forward<Tail>(t)...} {}

  private:
    T components[N];
};

int main() {
    double input[4] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
    SVectorN<double, 4> t(input);

    SVectorN<double, 4> c = {1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6};
    SVectorN<double, 4> d{1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6};
    SVectorN<double, 4> e(1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6);
}
```

I had to explicitly enforce presence of at least two arguments in the variadic ctor, otherwise it would be a better overload match for `t`'s construction and that would fail.

`c,d,e` are practically the same initialization if there is not ctor with `std::initializer_list`. Which there is not because initializing an array with one cannot be easily done.

Now, if you want to automatically deduce the template parameters, that is possible thanks to [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). To simplify that link, you have to just specify to the compiler how to deduce class's template arguments from a constructor's arguments.

For example the following:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
explicit SVectorN(const T (&)[N]) -> SVectorN<T, N>;
template <typename F, typename S, typename... Tail>
SVectorN(F &&, S &&, Tail &&...) -> SVectorN<F, sizeof...(Tail) + 2>;
```

will allow:

```
    SVectorN tx(input);
    SVectorN cx = {1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6};
    SVectorN dx{1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6};
    SVectorN ex(1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6);
```

Comment: Not sure if this would this work with 1 argument?

Comment: it could if you added SFINAE. Something vaguely akin to `is_constructable_from<T, First>`

Answer (score 0):

I really like the answer from @Quimby, but I'm not sure if it would work with one argument. Alternatively, you could overload the constructors with `std::initializer_list` and `variadic`. It's not very efficient at this stage, but you can optimize it as per your needs.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct SVectorN
{
    private:
        T components[N];
    
    public:
        SVectorN(const T(&another)[N])
        {
            std::copy(std::begin(another), std::end(another), components);
        }
    
        SVectorN(std::initializer_list<T> &&init_)
        {
            std::copy(std::begin(init_), std::end(init_), components);
        }
    
        template <typename ... U>
        SVectorN(U ...val_)
        {
            T tmp[] = { val_ ... };
            std::copy(std::begin(tmp), std::end(tmp), components);
        }
    
        void print() const
        {
            for (auto &&c : components)
                std::cout<< c <<",";
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    double input[4] = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 };
    
    SVectorN<double, 4> t(input);
    t.print();
    
    SVectorN<double, 4> c = { 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 };
    c.print();
    
    SVectorN<double, 4> d(1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 );
    d.print();
}
```

Results are:

```
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,
1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,
1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,
```

Online code: https://rextester.com/MIF22368

Comment: What if someone tries to copy construct from a `SVectorN&`?

Comment: @MooingDuck - By default, a copy ctor should work fine.. But, tbh I only addressed the specific questions from OP.

Comment: I thought the `template <typename ... U> SVectorN(U ...val_)` would be selected for a construction from `SVectorN&`, but apparently you're right, it works fine.
https://rextester.com/NAUNME93931

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've enjoyed your approach to constructors and written it down for other cases